# How can I print current user role in Twig?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm trying to get my user role thanks to a function in my theme.theme file.

```
function theme_get_user_role(){
  $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();
}
```

then in my view :

```
{% set roles = theme_get_user_role() %}
{{ dump(roles) }}
```

But I have this error :

> Twig_Error_Syntax : Unknown "theme_get_user_role" function. dans
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->getFunctionNodeClass()

What do I miss ?

Comment: A lot. Well, that's not the way how you would pass something into your template. You'd rather need to use a preprocess function.

Comment: I've also tried this (theme_template_preprocess_user) but nothing else append if I override the function

Comment: Yes, as you don't want to preprocess the user. You want to preprocess a view (at least that's what it sound like, correct me if wrong). So it probably would be something like `theme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables)` where you'd do your logic and then add the output to `$variables['foo'] = 'bar'` and in the corresponding template then access it via `{{ bar }}`.

Comment: I've added this theme_template_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) into theme.theme, but this is returning null (I tried to display "title", also returning null)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use below without any function. Because the User module provides the variable in preprocess for all templates: :

```
{% set roles = user.getroles(TRUE) %}
{{ dump(roles) }}
```

If you want to do anything only for the particular role then do this:

```
{% if 'ROLENAME' in user.getroles(TRUE)  %}
  <p>The user has the role "ABC".</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: already tried. This is giving me the list off all roles, I need current user role :)

Comment: If you want to exclude "authenticated" role you have to write some logic to get that. Drupal by default will provide "authenticated" role for all users. Updated answer to get current role.

Comment: I just need to get roles from my current user, I've added some roles and I want to show them, no matter if it's authenticated or not

Comment: What are the roles that your current user have? Can you list down here?  If you want to get all roles user `user.getroles()` and if you want to get all roles excluding of `authenticated` role use `user.getroles(TRUE)`

Comment: Commercial and Director

Comment: Then above edited answer will be perfect to use. It will give all roles of user excluding `authenticated` and print only `Commercial and Director` roles in twig.

Comment: This is working, but it's returning "directeur", but I need "Directeur", I believe this is taking the value in base but not the label, how can I get this ?

Comment: Sorry, No Idea on that.

Comment: @MorganTartreau – You could solve the upper case issue with mere CSS.

Comment: I did this directly in twig