# Get user field value in Twig

Tags: theming, users

I have a node--contentype.html.tiwg as well as a node--contentype--full.html.twig file in my template. In this files, I can get the nodes fields without any problem via {{ field.content.field_name.0 }}. What I want to achieve is, to get values from the currently logged in users fields as well. To be precise, I have added a "currency field" to the user profile, where the user sets his preferred currency. Now I want to use this value for an AJAX request to an API.

Is there any way to get these values? I tried it with {{ field.user.field_name.0 }}, but I get no output.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I found out, that I can get the the currency value of the node author via {{ node.uid.entity.field_currency.value }}. But instead, I want to get the currency value of the logged in user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print current user role in Twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268204/how-can-i-print-current-user-role-in-twig)

Comment: You can't do this in a node template. Use a block with a cache context for the current user.